# Jmeter setProperty

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

```
int counter;
System.out.println("counter in property: " + ${__property(countTimeCat1)});
System.out.println ("first time counter : " + ${__property(countTimeCat1,counter,0)});
System.out.println ("counter : " + counter);
counter = counter + 1;
${__setProperty(countTimeCat1, counter)};
System.out.println ("counter after adding :" + ${__property(countTimeCat1)});
```

I am trying to set a counter (just a sample here to try passing values in between threads. Main goal is to sum up all the response times for a particular http request and print it. I know reports can do it, but i need to use the total time for some calculations). The problem I have in this script is with setProperty. I am expecting the int value to be stored in "countTimeCat1", so that i can access this property in my next thread, but it is always getting set to "counter". What is that I am doing wrong? Any help highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In beanshell, to get the value,

```
props.get("propname")
```

to set,

```
props.put("countTimeCat1", Integer.toString(counter));
```